# Having problems when starting new activity (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml

**Edit**

---

**MainActivity.class:**

```
package com.rafapps.carteiradeaes.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void startCalculadorasActivity(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, calculadorasActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.rafapps.carteiradeaes.app.MainActivity"
android:background="#F2F2F2"><!-- Verde #9acd03 -->

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button_mercado"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background_set">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/heading_mercado"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp">


        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/icon_mercado"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_mercado"

            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_mercado"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/title_mercado"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon_mercado"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc_mercado"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/desc_mercado"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/heading_mercado"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button_carteira"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background_set">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/heading_carteira"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp">


        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/icon_carteira"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_carteira"

            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_carteira"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/title_carteira"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon_carteira"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc_carteira"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/desc_carteira"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/heading_carteira"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>



<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button_deolho"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background_set">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/heading_deolho"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp">


        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/icon_deolho"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_deolho"

            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_deolho"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/title_deolho"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon_deolho"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc_deolho"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/desc_deolho"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/heading_deolho"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button_calculadoras"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background_set"
    android:onClick="startCalculadorasActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/heading_calculadoras"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp">


        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/icon_calculadoras"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_calculadoras"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_calculadoras"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/title_calculadoras"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon_calculadoras"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc_calculadoras"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/desc_calculadoras"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/heading_calculadoras"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**calculadorasActivity.class**

```
package com.rafapps.carteiradeaes.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class calculadorasActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculadoras);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.calculadoras, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void startSimularVendaActivity(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, simularVendaActivity.class);
    MainActivity.startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

**activity_calculadoras.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.rafapps.carteiradeaes.app.MainActivity"
android:background="#F2F2F2"><!-- Verde #9acd03 -->

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button_simulacaoRendimento"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background_set"
    android:onClick="startSimularVendaActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/heading_simulacaoRendimento"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp">


        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/icon_simulacaoRendimento"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_simulacaorendimento"

            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_simulacaoRendimento"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/title_simulacaoRendimento"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon_simulacaoRendimento"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc_simulacaoRendimento   "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/desc_simulacaoRendimento"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/heading_simulacaoRendimento"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button_precoVenda"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background_set">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/heading_precoVenda"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp">


        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/icon_precoVenda"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_precovenda"

            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_precoVenda"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/title_precoVenda"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon_precoVenda"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc_precoVenda"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/desc_precoVenda"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/heading_precoVenda"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>



<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button_quantidadeAcoes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background_set">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/heading_quantidadeAcoes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp">


        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/icon_quantidadeAcoes"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_quantidadeacoes"

            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_quantidadeAcoes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/title_quantidadeAcoes"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon_quantidadeAcoes"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc_quantidadeAcoes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/desc_quantidadeAcoes"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/heading_quantidadeAcoes"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button_jurosCompostos"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background_set">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/heading_jurosCompostos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp">


        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/icon_jurosCompostos"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_juroscompostos"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_jurosCompostos"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/title_jurosCompostos"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon_jurosCompostos"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc_jurosCompostos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/desc_jurosCompostos"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/heading_jurosCompostos"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**simularVendaActivity.class**

```
package com.rafapps.carteiradeaes.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class simularVendaActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

// Definindo componentes do layout activity_simular_venda.xml

EditText editText_sv_quantidade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sv_edittext_quantidade);
EditText editText_sv_precocompra = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sv_edittext_precocompra);
EditText editText_sv_precovenda = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sv_edittext_precovenda);
EditText editText_sv_totaltaxas = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sv_edittext_totaltaxas);
CheckBox checkBox_sv_dobrartaxas = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.sv_checkbox_dobrartaxas);

//Definindo key-words para mÃ©todo putExtra()
public final static String SV_QUANTIDADE = "com.rafapps.carteiradeaes.app.QUANTIDADE";
public final static String SV_PRECOCOMPRA = "com.rafapps.carteiradeaes.app.PRECOCOMPRA";
public final static String SV_PRECOVENDA = "com.rafapps.carteiradeaes.app.PRECOVENDA";
public final static String SV_TOTALTAXAS = "com.rafapps.carteiradeaes.app.TOTALTAXAS";
public final static String SV_DOBRARTAXAS = "com.rafapps.carteiradeaes.app.DOBRARTAXAS";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_simular_venda);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.simular_venda, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void startRSimularVendaActivity(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, rSimularVendaActivity.class);
    String quantidade = editText_sv_quantidade.getText().toString();
    String precocompra = editText_sv_precocompra.getText().toString();
    String precovenda = editText_sv_precovenda.getText().toString();
    String totaltaxas = editText_sv_totaltaxas.getText().toString();
    String strDobrarTaxas;
    if (checkBox_sv_dobrartaxas.isChecked()) {
        strDobrarTaxas = "true";
    } else {
        strDobrarTaxas = "false";
    }
    Boolean dobrartaxas = Boolean.parseBoolean(strDobrarTaxas);

    if (quantidade.matches("")) {
        quantidade = "0";
    }
    if (precocompra.matches("")) {
        precocompra = "0";
    }
    if (precovenda.matches("")) {
        precovenda = "0";
    }
    if (totaltaxas.matches("")) {
        totaltaxas = "0";
    }
    intent.putExtra(SV_QUANTIDADE, quantidade);
    intent.putExtra(SV_PRECOCOMPRA, precocompra);
    intent.putExtra(SV_PRECOVENDA, precovenda);
    intent.putExtra(SV_TOTALTAXAS, totaltaxas);
    intent.putExtra(SV_DOBRARTAXAS, dobrartaxas);

    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

**activity_simular_venda.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.rafapps.carteiradeaes.app.simularVendaActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:text="@string/sv_textview_quantidade"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/sv_edittext_quantidade"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numeric="integer"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:text="@string/sv_textview_precocompra"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/sv_edittext_precocompra"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numeric="integer|decimal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:text="@string/sv_textview_precovenda"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/sv_edittext_precovenda"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numeric="integer|decimal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:text="@string/sv_textview_totaltaxas"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/sv_edittext_totaltaxas"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numeric="integer|decimal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    />
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/sv_checkbox_dobrartaxas"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/sv_checkbox_dobrartaxas"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>




<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button_simulacaoRendimento"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background_set"
    android:onClick="startRSimularVendaActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/heading_simulacaoRendimento"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:gravity="center">


        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/icon_simulacaoRendimento"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_simulacaorendimento"

            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_simulacaoRendimento"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/title_simulacaoRendimento"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon_simulacaoRendimento"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Had to erase it all because of the character limitation.

Comment: you should include the logcat output in your post

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to start activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SimularVendaActivity.class);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

and simularVendaActivity.class should be capital: 'S'imularVendaActivity.class
Remember, class names have to start with capital letters.

Comment: Well, when i do that i get two errors:
1) 'com.rafapps.appname.carteiradeaes.MainActivity' is not an enclosing class (at the first line)
2) Non-static method startActivity(android.content.Intent) cannot be referenced from a static context (at the second line)

Comment: Done. (didn't know that return key would actually post comment).

Comment: It is edited:Well, when i do that i get two errors: 1) 'com.rafapps.appname.carteiradeaes.MainActivity' is not an enclosing class (at the first line) 2) Non-static method startActivity(android.content.Intent) cannot be referenced from a static context (at the second line)

Comment: Can't answer my own question.. (Gotta have 10 reputation or more..) =(

Comment: As I review your code, I find that there is nothing assigned to the void that you start your activity. Maybe a button?

Comment: There's a onClick on the RelativeView (which is clickable) in calculadoras_activity.xml